# Angular 17: fileReplacements does not replace files

Tags: angular, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a C#/Angular 17 SPA project running in a docker container on an Azure App Service with multiple deployment slots. Basically, the production slot loads the image tagged "latest-prod" and the staging slot loads the image tagged "latest-staging". The containers are built automatically by YAML pipelines in Azure DevOps.

My angular.json file contains a configuration for staging (and production and development as well) and the required file replacement for the environment.ts (See [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements)):

```
    "configurations": {
        "staging": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    }
```

My pipeline build process looks like this:

```
displayName: Build and push image
steps:
- script: |
    cd ClientApp
    npm install
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    ng build --configuration=staging
    grep -q "staging" src/main* && echo "String found" || echo "String not found"
```

As you can see, I check the final build for the existence of the string "staging" which is inside the `environment.staging.ts` file like this:

```
environment: "staging",
```

In the pipeline, the script prints `"String not found"`

However, I ran `ng build --configuration=staging` locally on my machine. Running `grep` locally shows `"String found"`

So it looks like the file replacement works just fine locally, but not within the pipeline.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: The file replacement does not affect the file itself but the imports for this file.

Comment: @Aileron79 You need to check inside the dist folder for the replacement I think, not inside the source folder!

Comment: cat is checking upon your source folder, there are all your environment files there, both stagging and default one. Test your application directly by checking the loaded image.

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuRiegler and @GérômeGrignon - I tested again with the build in the `dist` directory. Strangely, the file has not been replaced in the pipeline, but it worked locally. I updated the question.

Comment: Make sure the code is same between local and remote git. You can publish the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` content after ng build command to devops artifact(PublishPipelineArtifact@1), then check the content with local, are they same for the src/main* file?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions, the solution was quite simple: The project is built in the Docker file, and I copied the Angular build from the pipeline Environment in the wrong place. This solved the issue (note the commented-out COPY where I originally copied the build):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80 443 8000 2222
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build


FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
###COPY ClientApp/dist /app/publish/ClientApp/

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY ClientApp/dist /app/wwwroot
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```